# Eyes getting sore and tired

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, amd-graphics

I know this questions have been asked before but, I want to focus on two areas which I think can solve my eyes getting sore and feeling tired all of the time when using Ubuntu.

I am using HP Pavilion dv6 laptop with Radeon graphics drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.

If someone can answer my three questions please:

One, how to to I update Ubuntu to the latest version of the Radeon driver?

Two, how to I check at what frequency the Pulse Width Modulation(PWM) in Ubuntu is running at?

Three, how do I increase the PWM?

I believe these are the reason my eyes are hurting using Ubuntu, If I can't get this fix then I would have to go to a non Linux OS as I have tried various distros with the same problem, and I don't really want to do that.

Thanks

Comment: As this was a problem with the hardware, please delete this question.

Comment: Why it is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the HP DV6 Pavillion Laptop I used at the time with AMD Display drivers, my eyes since recovered after swapping laptops.